# Stirling's approximation or analytical method, which is correct?

Tags: limits

Consider the limit :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{e^{x} x!}{x^{x}}$$

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), ie. :

$$x! \approx \sqrt{2\pi x} \left ( \frac{x}{e} \right )^{x}$$
The limit computes to $\infty $.

However, visualizing the limit as :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{e\cdot1}{x}\times \frac{e\cdot2}{x}\times  \frac{e\cdot3}{x}\times \cdots \times \frac{e\cdot x}{x}$$
We see that the first term tends to 0, so does the next one so on till the last one which is $e$. This makes the limit finite and much closer to 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that the number of terms in the product is not fixed, it goes to infinity too.

Comment: @TravisJ The second part was just an expansion of the factorial function in the numerator and the exponential in the denominator and numerator.

Comment: Stirling's approximation indicates that the terms you already have in the product don't go to zero fast enough to outweigh the new terms (each approximately equal to $e$) that you keep adding at the end as $x\to\infty$. But put an exponent of $x+1$ instead of $x$ in the denominator and things are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the number of terms you are multiplying together grows and the first term is not zero, just close to zero.  So if you have many terms which are larger than 1 being multiplied together, you can get a fairly large number.  If you multiply a large number by one close to zero the result is unpredictable--that is why $\infty\cdot 0$ is an indeterminate form.

To illustrate, I wrote a python script to generate a bunch of the terms in the sequence as you illustrate it.  The results are as follows:

**For $x$ in the range 2-20:**

```
 3.69452804947
 4.4634526496
 5.11857656561
 5.69906530954
 6.225752986
 6.71128419339
 7.16401493773
 7.58980791963
 7.99296390762
 8.37674860933
 8.74371099224
 9.09588584296
 9.43492819336
 9.76220568597
 10.078863923
 10.3858738707
 10.6840669959
 10.9741618062
 11.2567842313
```

**For $x$ in the range 200-220:**

```
 35.4638505322
 35.5523259114
 35.6405816574
 35.7286193977
 35.8164407398
 35.9040472718
 35.9914405622
 36.0786221607
 36.1655935981
 36.2523563869
 36.3389120218
 36.4252619795
 36.5114077192
 36.5973506831
 36.6830922963
 36.7686339675
 36.8539770889
 36.9391230367
 37.0240731712
 37.1088288373
 37.1933913643
```

Of course you might be skeptical that these terms have $x$ being too far from $\infty$ (even though the terms are clearly increasing as one might expect).  As your analytical argument using Stirling approximation shows, you should expect that $\frac{e^{x}x!}{x^x}$ behaves like $\sqrt{2\pi x}$ and be increasing.

I ran the script on much larger values of $x$, but there were numerical issues associated with floating point error.  So the computer treated the first terms as zero (not near zero) and the result came out to be zero.  This may also happen if you plug your terms into a calculator.